# How to change the background color of disqus comments?

Tags: css, disqus

I have been testing Disqus and noticed I can hardly see the comments I have entered. They seem to be in a white/pale grey font.
Is there any way to change the font color to black

here is the link

http://w3code.in/2015/10/send-private-message-using-facebook-api/

Answer (score 2):

I added this snippet to the main css file to fix it for good:

```
#dsq-content #dsq-comments .dsq-comment-body {
color: #fff;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Adjust the color values to your preference.

But for Chrome, the issue might be the order of execution. Javascript is executed after the CSS, which may be overwriting your customization. You'll have to change styles using javascript and then put it after disqus script.

Comment: updated your code on live site you can check the link but still no change

Comment: Finally it works but comments still now showing in chrome :(

Answer (score 1):

it's really easy to do:

```
#disqus_thread {
    background: red;
}
```

You can use elements' inspector to find classes and ids. Have fun!